# Strange output in JSON that I make in my PHP after an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am a bit new at this and totally messing something up.  I have a PHP result set through which I iterate like this:

```
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }

    echo json_encode($rows);
```

and then I output it like this in jQuery code:

```
success: function(json)
            {
                $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();

                // Here can update the right side of the screen with the newly entered information
        alert (json);

        var ob = $.parseJSON(json);

            alert (ob.creator_member_id);
            alert (ob.problem_title);
            alert (ob.problem_description);
            alert (ob.problem_date);


            }
```

But there is an error on the var ob = $.parseJSON(json); line it seems.  My JS console gives this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (D,E){return new n.fn.init(D,E)} has no method 'parseJSON'
```

What can this mean and how can I fix this?

Thanks!!

Comment: You can use eval to parse the Json. eval("'"+JSON+"'").

Comment: @Jitamaro  not very familiar with the jQuery world.  How would this look like?

Comment: I vote against aval, though it was extremely popular earlier. The safe way is using JSON.parse, see below.

JIC, for @Jitamaro's proposal it's not jQuery, but rather plain JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting JSON results via jQuery ajax call you don't need parsing resultant json - jQuery does it for you.

Just specify the

```
dataType: 'json'
```

[http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/], and your `success` handler will have the already parsed object.

If you want parsing JSON anywhay, try adding [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) to your project. You'll have to call `JSON.parse(json)` then.

Comment: I really just need to extract the values of the json. What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: I mean...there are n rows of data..how should I best loop through these and display them in one of the divs?

Comment: 1) use dataType: json as I proposed. then you success function will get a _normal_ _js_ _variable_ 2) you say it's an array? iterate over it in a normal way `for (var i = 0, l = res.length; i < l; ++i) { /*do whatever html black magic you need*/ }`

Comment: By the way, if it helps, I am trying it on this test page: http://www.problemio.com - I am outputing alerts of the data I am trying to get, but somehow it isn't working....going to try your solution with the loop now.....

Comment: alert (json); //var ob = $.parseJSON(json); alert ("1"); alert (ob.creator_member_id); — you commented the `ob` initialization but then try accessing its attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Jquery, too. eval is just plain JS and it suits my needs. I don't see any evil with this code but of course it's possible to inject bad code into a response. Probably it's not very good practise. It can be exploited for a reverse shell for example.